# Using Wilson's theorem for finding divisibility

Tags: number-theory

Use Wilson's Theorem to compute 9!  mod 13.  Do not just compute 9!  and
and it's remainder upon division by 11.  Hint:  relate 9! to 12!

I don't understand what is being said by "relate".

(13 - 1)! = -1 mod 13.

How do I relate that to 9!. It seems a stretch to relate this to 9!

Comment: The hint is to use that $12!=12\cdot 11\cdot 10\cdot 9!$.  I don't think that this hint is a particularly efficient or clever way of computing the answer.

Answer (score 1):

$12! = 9! \times 10 \times 11 \times 12 \equiv -1 $mod $13$.

Also $12! \equiv (-1)(-2)(-3)\times 9!$ mod $13$, 
so $9! \times 6 \equiv 1$ mod $13$

Thus $9! \equiv 11$ mod $13$ as the inverse of $6$ in $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{13\mathbb{Z}}$ is $11$

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're doing on the second line. Where is the $(-1)(-2)(-3)$ coming from

Comment: @user121615 $\ {\rm mod}\ p\!:\ \color{#c00}{p\equiv 0}\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#c00}p-i\,\equiv\, \color{#c00}0-i\,\equiv\, i $

Answer (score 1):

${\rm mod}\ p\!:\ {-}1 \equiv \overbrace{(p\!-\!1)(p\!-\!2)(p\!-\!3)(p\!-\!4)!\equiv (-1)(-2)(-3)(p\!-\!4)!}^{\Large\qquad\qquad\quad p\,-\,i\ \ \equiv\ \ -i\,\pmod p}\equiv \color{#c00}{-6}(p\!-\!4)!$

When $\, p = 6k\!+\!1\,$ then $\,{\rm mod}\ p\!:\ \color{#c00}{{-6}}k\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\,(p\!-\!4)!\equiv -k\ $ by scaling above by $\,k$

$\,p = 13 = 6\cdot \color{#0a0}2+1\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#0a0}{k=2},\,$ therefore $\,9! = (p\!-\!4)!\equiv \color{#0a0}{-k\equiv -2}\equiv 11$